# How do I send compass app data to apple watch?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, compass

Ok, I was very disappointed to know iWatch doesn't come with a most basic wrist watch feature: a compass.
It's reasonable that due to magnets used in coils and straps, it's not possible to include a magnetic sensor.
But is there any way we can send the data of iPhone's compass app to watch. Better yet, a complication?

I have Googled it online, but found no luck.

Comment: What does "compass data" mean to you? Simple mirroring of compass app from the phone while it's in your bag or pocket? How would the watch wake up the phone and even activate the compass? This seems to predicate there being a compass API and that isn't even established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to get data from the iPhone's Compass app to your Apple Watch, and no complication option available. There is no API on watchOS for compass heading and you would need to have your iPhone / iPad out and pointing in a specific location for the watch to match the iOS device.

I suppose you could mount the phone to a stand inside a ship or vehicle and know that the watch is showing where the other device is pointing and not necessarily where your watch is "pointing"

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_heading_and_course_information

This sort of "making do with what's available" is documented here in open source as well as dozens of App Store apps where no one in particular stands out as good or useful to me.

- https://github.com/woutercx/iOS.Compass.Sample

You would have to adapt that for watchOS complication and iOS companion app. 
In the Watch app on your iPhone you'll find an App Store icon on the bottom that allows you to search for Apple Watch apps directly. You'll find there's a number of Compass apps available you can try doing exactly what the code above allows and no more or no less.

There isn't a magnetometer in the watch so it doesn't get it's own magnet in early 2019 at least.

Comment: Searched, found nothing relevant. I'll wait/look for a solution and mark this answer correct if it's indeed not possible. Thanks!

Comment: @innocentrock It's still not possible. I added code and more words explaining why it's not viable. Best to get a $20 magnetic compass if you need a small one that's super accurate and let your watch do other duties for 2019.